# Prove that if $a\equiv b \pmod {p^{2}-p}$, then $a^{a}\equiv b^{b} \pmod{p}$ where $p$ is any prime and $a$ and $b$ are nonzero integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have shown the case in which $p=2$, so now I'm considering $p\geq 3$. I see that $p^{2}-p = p(p-1)$, in which case we can apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to obtain $a\equiv [b,b] \mod{[p,\phi(p)]}$, since $p$ and $(p-1)$ are coprime and $\phi(p)=(p-1)$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. Also, I see that $a\equiv b \pmod{\phi(p)}$ implies that $x^a\equiv x^b \pmod{p}$ for some $x\in \Phi(p)$ by the Fermat-Euler theorem. However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach or how to continue from here. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Now I see that $x^a\equiv x^b \pmod{p}$ is true for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. Because $p$ is prime, $x$ will either be coprime, or a multiple of $p$. In each case the statement is still true. This is why we can let $x = b$. Then we can use $a^a\equiv b^a \pmod{p}$ and $b^a\equiv b^b \pmod{p}$, and we're done.

Comment: You are basically done. By $a\equiv_p b$ we have $a^a\equiv_p b^a$. Then, as you said yourself (set $x=b$), we have $b^a\equiv_p b^b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

By the *Chinese remainder theorem*, the  hypothesis is equivalent to $a\equiv b\mod p$ AND $a\equiv b\mod p-1$.

Now *lil' Fermat* states that $\;a^a\equiv \bigl((a\bmod p)^{a\bmod p-1}\bigr)\bmod p$, and similarly for $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $p\ge 3$ and note that $p(p-1)\mid a-b$ iff $p\mid a-b$ and $p-1 \mid a-b$. So $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder modulo $p$ and modulo $p-1$. Moreover, the sequences $(a^n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(b^n)_{n\ge 1}$ are periodic modulo $p-1$, which implies that
$$
a^x \equiv b^y \bmod{p}
$$
whenever $x \equiv y \bmod{p-1}$. But $x=a$ and $y=b$ verify this condition by hypothesis.